# Lines on the side of the screen

Tags: android

There are maybe 3px lines of my primary color on the sides of the image. I don't know why are they there. I tried almost everything. Here is the code :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewplaces"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/pyrros" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/caj_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageViewplaces"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGFoT.png)